# Attempting to set alpha value of color changes color

Tags: java, image, image-processing

I created this code in order to remove all semi-transparent colors from an image and make them fully opaque. For some reason, the colors of the image change drastically, even though im only changing the alpha. Attached is the code and an example of what happens to the image.

Before:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLU1v.png]

After:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SObz.png]

```
public class Main {
    
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        
        File file = new File("karambitlore.png");
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(fis);
        
        image = convertToType(image, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        
        BufferedImage image2 = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        
        for (int width = 0; width < image.getWidth(); width++)
        {
            for (int height = 0; height < image.getHeight(); height++)
            {

                int rgb = image.getRGB(width, height);

                boolean transparent = (rgb & 0xFF000000) == 0x0;
                boolean opaque = (rgb & 0xFF000000) == 0xFF000000;
                
                if (!transparent && !opaque)
                {
                    
                    rgb = rgb | 0xFF000000;
                    
                    image2.setRGB(width, height, rgb);
                    
                } else
                {
                    image2.setRGB(width, height, image.getRGB(width, height));

                }
                
            }
        }
       
        fis.close();
        ImageIO.write(image2, "png", file);
        
        System.out.println(image.getType());
        
    }
    
    public static BufferedImage convertToType(BufferedImage image, int type) {
        BufferedImage newImage = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), type);
        Graphics2D graphics = newImage.createGraphics();
        graphics.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
        graphics.dispose();
        return newImage;
            
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't see that the color change drastically. I do see that the edges of the second image is not as sharp. I would guess this is because the anti aliasing is not as effective? No idea how to fix it.

Comment: @camickr The code only affects those outermost parts as they are the only semi-transparent areas on the entire image. Every pixel that is modified by "rgb = rgb | 0xFF000000" becomes discolored. If you zoom into the image, you can see that there are some different colored pixels that seem to have appeared out of nowhere

Comment: Those could be nearly transparent colored pixels in the original image.

Comment: Rather than just making semi-transparent pixels fully opaque, it might be better to blend them with a background color.

Comment: To get a better result, you need to actually compute the RGB contributions for each semi-transparent pixel (which is basically the same as blending). You should probably also use a threshold, say 50%, and only make pixels that are more opaque than this threshold fully opaque (below threshold should be set to transparent).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem with your input image is that it has a nearly-transparent "halo" around the fully transparent pixels, kind of like a "dithered" transparency. When you turn these pixels fully opaque, they a) create opaque pixels where you don't want them, and b) make these pixels way too saturated as the pixels are not premultiplied with alpha (you can google "premultiplied alpha" if you are interested in alpha compositing/blending). Note that the pixels don't really "change color", it's just that they normally don't contribute much to the end result as they are almost fully transparent.

The easy fix, that works ok regardless of background color, is just to use a threshold value to decide whether the pixel should be transparent.

If you know the background color (either solid or some "average") you can blend the pixel color with the background color, using the alpha value. This will create smoother edges, but ONLY against this background. You may use a lower threshold in this case.

Here's a modified version of your code that produces better results for your input:

```java
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    File file = new File(args[0]);

    BufferedImage image = convertToType(ImageIO.read(file), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

    Color bg = Color.ORANGE; // Change to the color of your background, if you want to blend

    int bgR = bg.getRed();
    int bgG = bg.getGreen();
    int bgB = bg.getBlue();


    for (int width = 0; width < image.getWidth(); width++) {
        for (int height = 0; height < image.getHeight(); height++) {
            int rgb = image.getRGB(width, height);

            int opaqueness = (rgb >>> 24) & 0xFF;

            if (opaqueness > 100) { // The threshold 100 works fine for your current input, tune to suit other needs
                // Fully opaque
                image.setRGB(width, height, rgb | 0xFF000000);

                // Or if you prefer blending the background:
/*
                // Multiply alpha
                int r = ((rgb >> 16 & 0xFF) * opaqueness) + (bgR * (0xFF - opaqueness)) >> 8;
                int g = ((rgb >>  8 & 0xFF) * opaqueness) + (bgG * (0xFF - opaqueness)) >> 8;
                int b = ((rgb       & 0xFF) * opaqueness) + (bgB * (0xFF - opaqueness)) >> 8;

                image.setRGB(width, height, r << 16 | g << 8 | b | 0xFF000000);
*/
            } else {
                // Fully transparent
                image.setRGB(width, height, rgb & 0xFFFFFF);
            }
        }
    }

    ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File(file.getParentFile(), file.getName() + "_copy_bg_mult.png"));
}

public static BufferedImage convertToType(BufferedImage image, int type) {
    BufferedImage newImage = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), type);
    Graphics2D graphics = newImage.createGraphics();
    graphics.setComposite(AlphaComposite.Src);
    graphics.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
    graphics.dispose();
    return newImage;

}
```

The code as-is will create an image like this, and it will have slightly jagged edges, but the "halo" is removed:

[image]

Or, if you comment out the "Fully opaque" version, and comment in the "Multiply alpha" section, you can get an image like this (which will obviously only look good against a yellow background):

[image]